# Meaning of “Je suis ce que je suis”

Tags: sens, proverbes, philosophie

There is an interesting sentence

> Je suis ce que je suis.

Now I've got two versions of its meaning, one of which is

> I am what I follow.

while the other is

> I follow what I am

Both seem to make sense to me. But which one indeed is its real meaning in French? Since this sentence sounds kinda like a proverb or an idiom, there can be of course only one version that is correct.

Comment: None of the above ... "I am what I am."

Comment: @jlliagre is this a proverb or idiom?

Comment: It is equally known in English: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_What_I_Am

Comment: It’s probably not a good idea for me to argue with your premise (that sentences sounding like a proverb or an idiom can, of course, have only one correct version/meaning), but I believe that this sentence, depending on the context, could possibly have the two meanings that you suggest, plus two others, i.e.,“I follow what I follow” & “I am what I am” (the latter, of course, being by far its most common meaning). “Je suis QUI je suis” would only mean one thing to me (I am WHO I am), but I’m not convinced that “je suis ce que je suis” can have one, & only one meaning, regardless of the context.

Comment: @PapaPoule The other meanings are of course technically possible but in the real life, they are only used in a humoristic context (like the riddle in my reply).

Comment: And in the age of the Internet, "I am what I follow" may have acquired a new meaning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Je suis ce que je suis* appears in the Bible (*ego sum qui sum* / Ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ ὤν / אֶהְיֶה אֲשֶׁר אֶהְיֶה ) commonly translated in English by "I am that I am".

There are common variants:

> Je suis comme je suis
>
> Je suis qui je suis

There is however a well known case where "suis" is deliberately used ambiguously:

> Je suis ce que je suis, mais je ne suis pas ce que je suis. Si j'étais ce que je suis, je ne serais pas ce que je suis. Qui suis-je ?

Answer:

> Je suis un berger qui suis son mouton.

Comment: Haha that's brilliant.

Comment: Ou encore : mon ombre, mon chemin, ....

Comment: Adapte la conjugaison dans ta réponse cachée, ça perturbe encore un peu plus. :)

Answer (score 3):

*I follow what I follow* is correct too, altthough less likely to be intended in the context. A tautology in both cases. A tautology is a tautology, but not *only* a tautology.

As the proverb says

> Quand on voit ce qu'on voit, et qu'on sait ce qu'on sait, on a raison de penser ce qu'on pense.

Answer (score 3):

As a proverbe the sentence "Je suis ce que je suis" means "I am that I am"/"I am what I am"/"I am as I am".

But in other contexts, it can be any of these combinations: 
I am what I am 
I am what I follow 
I follow what I am
I follow what I follow.

Actually "Je suis" meaning "I follow" and "Je suis" meaning "I am" are both written and pronounced the same.

Comment: Réponse la plus complète et factuelle.

Answer (score 0):

My high school French teacher MANY years ago used this as a riddle:  In English - "I am what I am; I am not what I follow.  If I am what I follow, I am not what I am."  What am I?  Answer: a shadow

In French: Je suis ce que je suis; je ne suis pas ce que je suis. Si je suis ce que je  suis, je ne suis pas ce que je suis.  (This was  many years ago - I am not sure I remember the French exactly!)

Comment: Bienvenue 31478,  this riddle is already given in another answer here.  Please do stick around to [tour] the site and see the French language SE [help].

Comment: Probablement Si j'étais ce que je suis, je ne serais pas ce que je suis for the second sentence.